# Data is not displaying nodejs handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to display data from my database but it doesnt seem to show up, what I did is followed a tutorial for this on ejs and it seemed to work fine and I am now trying it on handlebars

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
  req.db.collection('users').find().sort({"_id": -1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', err);
      res.render('user/list', {
        title: 'Users List', 
        data: ''
      });
    } else {
      res.render('user/list', {
        title: 'Users List', 
        data: result
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Desciption</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
{{#if user}}{{#each user}}
<tr>
  <td>{{this.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{this.Type}}</td>
  <td>{{this.Description}}</td>
  <td>
    <div style="float:left">
      <a href='/users/edit/{{ user._id}}'>Edit</a> &nbsp;             
      <form method="post" action="/users/delete/{{user._id}}" style="float:right">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value='Delete' onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}{{/if}}
</table>
```

This is the ejs project that I made by following a tutorial and it currently  is working

```
<table width='80%' border=0>

<tr style='text-align:left; background-color:#CCC'>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>

<!--
  Using FOREACH LOOP for the users array

  myArray.forEach(function(el, index) {
    // el - current element, i - index
  });
-->
<% if (data) { %>
  <% data.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.Name %></td>
      <td><%= user.Type %></td>
      <td><%= user.Description %></td>
      <td>
        <div style="float:left">
          <a href='/users/edit/<%= user._id %>'>Edit</a> &nbsp;             
          <form method="post" action="/users/delete/<%= user._id %>" style="float:right">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value='Delete' onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% }) %>
<% } %>
</table>
```

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) { 
  // fetch and sort users collection by id in descending order
  req.db.collection('benefits').find().sort({"_id": -1}).toArray(function(err, result) {

    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', err);
      res.render('user/list', {
        title: 'User List', 
        data: ''
      });
    } else {

      res.render('user/list', {
        title: 'User List', 
        data: result
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I just tried to convert the ejs code to handle bars with some reasearch on how it works but it did not turn out my way

I am still a beginner in using nodejs so please go easy on me

Comment: Sorry, this is unclear if you have a problem with the current code or if you have problem rewriting it with Handlebars. In this last case, would you show us the current handlebars code you wrote so far?

Comment: I have fixed it now please check the handlebars code that I have placed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only you have to convert your templates from ejs to handlebars, but you also have to use handlebars middleware with express.

Here you will find one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Install it with, for example npm : `npm install --save express-handlebars`

Then, declare it in your server file :

```
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();
```

**Edit:**

I see that you use a kind of 'partials' to render your users' list page, so you have to declare its path :

```
var hbs = exbphbs.create({
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  partialsDir: 'views/partials/',
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Now your workspace should look like this :

```
app.js
views/
  list.handlebars
  layouts/
    main.handlebars
  partials/
    user/
      list.handlebars
```

In your template, you check the presence of a `user` var, so you have to name it in the render function, instead of `data:`. Plus, render the file `list.handlebars`

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  req.db.collection('users').find().sort({"_id": -1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', err);
      res.render('list', {
        title: 'Users List', 
        user: '',
      });
    } else {
      res.render('list', {
        title: 'Users List', 
        user: result,
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**views/list.handlebars :**

```
{{> user/list}}
```

**views/layouts/main.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
{{body}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**views/partials/user/list.handlebars** : notice i removed `this.` and `user.`

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Desciption</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  {{#if user}}
    {{#each user}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>
        <td>{{Type}}</td>
        <td>{{Description}}</td>
        <td>
          <div style="float:left">
            <a href='/users/edit/{{ _id}}'>Edit</a> &nbsp;
            <form method="post" action="/users/delete/{{_id}}" style="float:right">
              <input type="submit" name="delete" value='Delete' onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I have done that and my defaultLayout: is set to my layout page (header) should I do that witht the current page too?